# entt basic_registry::get<>() explanation

Tags: c++, stdtuple, entt

Currently using g++11.3.0, C++20.

Could anyone explain how the basic_registry's `get<>()` template function is able to function such that when retrieving a single component through a call like `auto& comp {registry.get<A>()};`, the component itself can be directly assigned to and/or accessed like a normal reference, and when retrieving multiple components through a call like `registry.get<A, B, C>()`, it can be unpacked via a structured binding `auto& [a, b, c]`.

Code (from https://skypjack.github.io/entt/registry_8hpp_source.html)

```
template<typename... Type>
[[nodiscard]] decltype(auto) get([[maybe_unused]] const entity_type entt) {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Type) == 1u) {
        return (const_cast<Type &>(std::as_const(*this).template get<Type>(entt)), ...);
    } else {
        return std::forward_as_tuple(get<Type>(entt)...);
    }
}
```

Comment: its a `std::tuple` or a single element. Which part specifically do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function template returns a tuple:

```
template <typename ...T>
auto foo() {
    return std::make_tuple(T{}...);
}
```

You can call it via

```
auto [a, b, c] = foo<int,int,double>();
```

---

The following function template returns just a `T`:

```
template <typename T>
auto bar() { return T{};}
```

you can call it via

```
auto d{bar<int>()};
```

---

Functions can have only one return type. `foo` and `bar` are function templates. The functions `foo<int,int,double>` and `bar<int>` have one return type. They return one value.

---

The following function template selects between two function templates to be instantiated and called depending on the number of template arguments:

```
template <typename ...T>
auto moo() {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(T) == 1u) { return bar<T...>(); }
    else return foo<T...>();
}
```

You can call it via:

```
auto [x,y,z] = moo<int,int,double>();
```

Or

```
auto w{ moo<int>()};
```

---

Note that when `T...` is more than a single argument then `bar<T...>` would be a mismatch (because `bar` has only a single argument. However, with `constexpr if` in template context the not taken branch is discarded at compile time.

---

In the case of `sizeof...(T) == 1u` the parameter pack is expanded. However, the expansion is only a single type in this case (otherwise `bar<T...>` would not compile). It could have been written as

```
template <typename T,typename ...More>
auto moo() {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(More) == 0u) { return bar<T>(); }
    else return foo<T,More...>();
}
```

---

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n6MrYqd36)

---

Comment: I was confused because I thought that in a non-void function all return statements had to return a value of the same type. But I guess the instantiation of a function template at each return statement bypasses that?

Comment: @incur8203 `constexpr if` in a template context discards the branch that is not taken.

Comment: Ohh... never knew what `constexpr if` did till now.